# Error with curl

Tags: curl, iot

I am trying to send some data to the internet of things service using curl.

I have configured the PATH and curl is accessible.

But when i try to pus a data (Measure) using the below link,i get a message:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"201\", \"sensorTypeAlternateId\": \"857\", \"measures\": [{\"Inctemp\": \"25\"}] }"http://127.0.0.1:8699/measures/1c2639b9c113ef54

curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Can you please help.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe there's a nested string error. So it thinks the url is still part of the entered data. Try maybe something like this for the data:
`'{"stuff":"moreStuff"}'`

Comment: Hi...do you mean someting like this:curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "'{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"201\", \"sensorTypeAlternateId\": \"857\", \"measures\": [{\"Inctemp\": \"25\"}] }'"http://127.0.0.1:8699/measures/1c2639b9c113ef54

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out.
There's not space between the end of your data string and the beginning of the URL!!!

So it thinks it's all one long value for `-d`

Comment: Try this code instead:
`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"201\", \"sensorTypeAlternateId\": \"857\", \"measures\": [{\"Inctemp\": \"25\"}] }" http://127.0.0.1:8699/measures/1c2639b9c113ef54` (Notice the space between `}"` and `http`

Comment: That worked,thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Just to finalize this question so that it can be fully answered:
Your request is fine except for a small syntax error.

Your code:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"201\", \"sensorTypeAlternateId\": \"857\", \"measures\": [{\"Inctemp\": \"25\"}] }"http://127.0.0.1:8699/measures/1c2639b9c113ef54
```

Correct code:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"capabilityAlternateId\": \"201\", \"sensorTypeAlternateId\": \"857\", \"measures\": [{\"Inctemp\": \"25\"}] }" http://127.0.0.1:8699/measures/1c2639b9c113ef54
```

(Notice the space between the end of the `-d` option `}"` and the beginning of the request URL `http`